# 425 Can't open data connection on my program whereas Filezilla work

Tags: c++, sockets, upload, ftp

I try to make a FTP client which upload a file in active mode(C++ with the socket library of linux).
My program works when I want to send a file on a local server(LAN) but it 
doesn't work when I want to send a file on a remote server(WAN).
I have the error 425 Can't open data connection. I've made many research
and in general this problem come from the NAT (which can possibly blocked
the data connexion port).But I've tried with Filezilla(in active mode) and it worked. 
So I don't find where is the problem with the data connection.

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
int sock;
int sock_data,new_sock;
struct sockaddr_in sin_data;
struct sockaddr_in cli_addr = {0};

char* receiving(int socket)
{
    char message[1000] = {'/0'};
    recv(socket,message,sizeof(message),0);
    cout << message << endl;
    return message;
}

void *send_data(void* args)
{
    send(sock,"STOR fichier.txt\r\n",sizeof("STOR fichier.txt\r\n"),0);
    receiving(sock);
    return(0);
}

void *accept_data_connexion(void* args)
{
    sock_data = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,6);
    sin_data.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin_data.sin_port = htons(58703);
    sin_data.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    new_sock = accept(sock_data,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,&clilen);
    if(errno == 0)
        {
        cout << "Data connection is established" << endl;
        }
}

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(21);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx");
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,6);
    //connection
    connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(sin));
    receiving(sock);
    receiving(sock);
    print_box();
    //log in
    send(sock,"USER username\r\n",sizeof("USER username\r\n"),0);
    receiving(sock);
    send(sock,"PASS password\r\n",sizeof("PASS password\r\n"),0);
    receiving(sock);

    send(sock,"SYST\r\n",sizeof("SYST\r\n"),0);
    receiving(sock);
    send(sock,"PWD\r\n",sizeof("PWD\r\n"),0);
    receiving(sock);
    send(sock,"PORT xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,229,79",sizeof("PORT xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,229,79"),0);
    receiving(sock);
    send(sock,"TYPE I \r\n",sizeof("TYPE I \r\n"),0);
    receiving(sock);

    pthread_t th1, th2;
    void *ret;
    pthread_create (&th1,NULL, accept_data_connexion,(void*)1);
    pthread_create (&th2, NULL, send_data,(void *)2);
    (void)pthread_join (th1, &ret);
    (void)pthread_join (th2, &ret);

    ifstream fichier("fichier.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while(fichier.eof() == false)
     {
        fichier.seekg(i,fichier.beg);
        char* buffer= new char[1];
        fichier.read(buffer,1);
        write(new_sock,buffer,1);
        i++;
     }

    fichier.close();
    close(new_sock);
    close(sock_data);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use traffic capture tools like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to see what commands other client sends to server.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that `accept_data_connexion()` is not calling `bind()` and `listen()` to actually open the data port before then calling `accept()` to receive a data connection.

What you have shown is a terrible implementation in general.  You are making a lot of mistakes. Misuse of `sizeof()`. Lack of error handling, both in the socket API and the FTP protocol.  Memory leaks. Using threads where they are not needed.  You really need to step back and think about what you are doing.  Either re-write this code from scratch to do things properly, or use a third-party library that handles the details for you, such as [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: Sorry I've accidently erase the method bind() and listen() before 
sent my question. I correct it here. http://pastebin.com/wiSctWC2
My purpose is to make a functional program before handle the details. 
I don't understand why thread are not needed. When we send a PORT 
command to the server he don't establish a connection directly but 
he wait a command like STOR. When I make STOR command,FTP server 
want to establish a connection on my program. So my program listen 
on a port and send the command STOR in the same time. It's the 
reason why I use thread. Am I wrong ?

Comment: You don't need a thread for that. Open the port with `bind`/`listen` and send `PORT` but do not call `accept` yet. Then send `STOR`, and if the server replies with 125 or 150 then call `accept()`. If the server does not connect, timeout `accept()` after awhile and send `ABOR`.